# How can I solve session close issue in Whatsapp-web.js

Tags: node.js, session, render, whatsapp, whatsapp-cloud-api

I have build a teaching AI assistant using Open AI and WhatsApp-web.js. I deployed it on Render but after every 10 minutes session get closed, and it stops responding. How can I fix it?

This is the err:

> Error: Protocol error (Runtime.callFunctionOn): Session closed. Most likely the page has been closed.
>
> Feb 8 11:34:07 AM at CDPSession.send (/opt/render/project/src/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/Connection.js:218:35)